# Using OOP to create a list of names

Tags: python, list, class, oop, dictionary

I am going through LPTHW and am on ex 42 (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html), I think I have a decent grasp on the is-a and has-a concept, but in the study drills he asks us to add lists and dicts to the classes to make this somewhat of a more functional script. I was thinking of adding a list to both dog, cat, and a dict to person or employee in order to store the values for names and in the employee case also salaries. I have no clue how to do this and make it functional, could someone give me just a short example of what I am trying to do and I will build from there to complete the rest. Thank you, also code below...

Quick example of what I am getting at...

```
class Animal(object):
    pass

## Dog is-a Animal
class Dog(Animal):
   def __init__(self, name):
        ##Dog has-a name
        self.name = name
        self.doglist = []

Dog.doglist.append("Rover")
```

When I do the above I get an error 'AttributeError: type object 'Dog' has no attribute doglist.

Full code:

```
##Animal is-a object (yes, sort of confusing) look at the extra credit
class Animal(object):
    pass

## Dog is-a Animal
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ##Dog has-a name
        self.name = name


##Cat is-a animal
class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ##Cat has-a name
        self.name = name

##Person is-a object
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ##Person has-a name
        self.name = name


        ##Person has-a pet
        self.pet = None


##Employee is-a Person
class Employee(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        ## not sure what this does
        super(Employee, self).__init__(name)
        ##Person has-a salary
        self.salary = salary

##Fish is a class
class Fish(object):
    pass

##Salmon is-a fish and is a class
class Salmon(Fish):
    pass

##Halibut is-a fish
class Halibut(Fish):
    pass

##rover is-a Dog
rover = Dog("Rover")


##satan is-a Cat
satan = Cat("Satan")

##mary is a person
mary = Person("Mary")

##Mary has-a pet named satan
mary.pet = satan

##frank is-a employee that has-a salary of 120,000
frank = Employee("Frank", 120000)

##frank has-a pet rover(dog)
frank.pet = rover

##flipper is-a instance of Fish
flipper = Fish()

##crouse is-a instance of salmon
crouse = Salmon()

##harry is-a instance of Halibut
harry = Halibut()

print frank.pet.name
```

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is to put the functionality in the class were it belongs and use it in all the subclasses. Why not add a list to `Animal` and a dict to `Person`? Also, I'm not sure what you want. Does this code not work or does it behave unexpectedly? Is there something it's _not_ doing?

Comment: No it works perfectly. I do want to add a list to `Animal`, and a dict to `Person`, but I don't know how to properly format it... for example, would I simply put `self.Animallist = []` in animal to create a list there? And how do I append to that list? `self.Animallist.append = 'randomname'` because I think I tried that and it didnt work...

Comment: `append()` is a method not an attribute. To use it `list.append(thing_to_append)`. So it will work if you use `self.animal_list =[]`. All you need to do if `cat` is an instance of `Cat()` is `cat.animal_list.append(cat_thing)`

Comment: Thanks Ian I will give that a try... ahh so maybe add `self.Animallist = []` and then use `self.Animallist.append('randomname")`? I will try this

Comment: I tried this but I am getting some piece of the syntax wrong here... See above error that I keep getting and example I put in the original post... I am missing something here and I am sure its sadly simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Animal(object):
    pass

## Dog is-a Animal
class Dog(Animal):
   def __init__(self, name):
        ##Dog has-a name
        self.name = name
        self.doglist = []

Dog.doglist.append("Rover")
```

The reason this doesn't work is because you haven't initialized a `Dog` object. To correct this:

```
dog = Dog('Fido')
dog.doglist.append('Rover')
```

When you set an attribute inside the `__init__` method you have to initialize it first to access the property otherwise it doesn't exist. If you want to have all `Dog` objects share the same list you can:

```
class Dog:
    dog_list = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

then

```
>>> Dog.dog_list.append('Fido')
>>> Dog.dog_list
['Fido']
>>> dog = Dog('Rover')
>>> dog.dog_list
['Fido']
>>> dog.dog_list.append('Rover')
>>> dog.dog_list
['Fido', 'Rover']
>>> Dog.dog_list
['Fido', 'Rover']
```

Properties declared outside a method will be shared between all instances of that class.

Comment: This was exactly the type of explanation I was looking for! I would upvote but i have no reputation ha. Thank you so much I truly appreciate it and this really helped me grasp the concept.

Comment: I am adding a comment just to say thank you again, you helped me a ton, really appreciate it.